# Scheme - Return list of N Repetitions of said list

Tags: scheme, racket

First off, this is a homework question so just looking for guidance and not an answer.

Write a function named (cycle ALIST N) that accepts a list of elements ALIST and an integer N. This function returns a list containing N repetitions of the elements of ALIST. If N is non-positive, this function returns the empty list.

I will be honest in that I'm not sure how to begin solving this problem. I've been thinking of writing a helper function then using cons calling this n times but just looking if I'm on the correct track here.

Comment: Hint: Do you know of a function that does this for the special case of two lists - `(something '(1 2) '(1 2)) --> '(1 2 1 2)`?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, I'll do some research. Scheme has still been a struggle for me.

Comment: Ah I got it, I can use append in this case!

Answer (score 0):

One of the more common ways to tackle recursive problems is to begin thinking about it at the end. In other words, under what conditions should you stop? —When are you done? If you can write this base case down, then you only need to ask, what do I do when I am one step away from stopping? This is the recursive step, and for relatively simple recursive problems you are done as the whole problem is either "continue" to do the same thing or "stop."

Knowing the base case usually tells you what kind of extra information you may need to carry around, if any.

In the case of scheme and racket, which support *tail call optimization*, you may end up with different kinds of recursion. For example:

```
(define (normal-factorial n)
  (if (zero? n)
      1
      (* n (normal-factorial (- n 1)))))

(define (tail-factorial n)
  (letrec ((tf (lambda (product index)
                 (if (zero? index)
                     product
                     (tf (* product index) (- index 1))))))
    (tf n (- n 1))))
```

In the first case, we build up a product without ever multiplying until the very end, while in the second we multiply as soon as possible and carry around this temporary product the whole time.

Not all problems easily lend themselves to one kind of recursion or the other.

Comment: Thank you for this, actually extremely helpful in just thinking through recursion problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have different strategies you can make. The simplest is probably not the most effiecent but the one that produces less code:

```
(require srfi/26) ; cut
(define (cycle lst n)
  (define dup-lst (map (cut make-list n <>) lst)) 
  (foldr append '() dup-lst))
```

So what this does is that the `map` creates a list of lists where each is `n` elements of each. The `foldr` flattens it by using `append`.

With more hands on you can make it more efficient. I'm thinking roll your own recursion consing the elements from end to beginning in an accumulator:

```
(define (cycle lst n)
  (let helper ((lst (reverse lst)) (c n) (acc '()))
    (cond ((null? lst) acc)
          ((<= c 0) (helper ...))
          (else (helper ...)))))
```

I've left out the recursive parts. What this does is a base case on the empty list, a reset recur with a `c` reset to `n` and the `cdr` when `c` is zero and the default case keeping `lst` while reducing `c` and `cons`-ing the first element of `lst` to `acc`. This is a O(n) solution.

Comment: Now correct me If I'm misunderstanding, but is (require srfi/26) an extra library? We aren't allowed to use third-party libraries so just make sure. Also I've been trying to implement the idea of using a helper function where I pass in the same list twice and just return a new list using cons, wondering if this a poor way to think about it